# Divide 2D array into continuous regions of as-equal-as-possible sums?

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array of floating-point numbers, and I'd like to divide this array into an arbitrary number of regions such that the sum of all the regions' elements are more or less equal. The regions must be continuous. By as-equal-as-possible, I mean that the standard deviation of the region sums should be reduced as much as possible.

I'm doing this because I have a map of values corresponding to the "population" in an area, and I want to divide this area into groups of relatively equal population.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you currently studying dynamic programming algorithms?

Comment: sharing some example array is a good idea so we grasp its properties better

Comment: define "equal(-ish)" please

Comment: My assumption concerning the definition of "equal(-ish)": The difference between any pair of sums should be minimal. So it's an optimization problem. More interesting might be whether the "arbitrary" number of regions is a fixed input value. Regardless of that, examples (including "extreme" inputs like `[1,1,1,1,10000000]`) might help for a general understanding

Comment: I'll add an example as soon as possible, but yes, this is an optimization problem where the goal is to reduce the standard deviation of the sums of each region.

Comment: are there any constrains on the regions ? for example you do not divide towns or you area is single city an want divide by districts. also what shapes can be used ? some processes demand strict area properties so I am adding this just to be sure and no one waste time with unusable solution in the future ...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1.compute the whole sum

2.compute local centers of mass (coordinates)

3.now compute the region sum

- for example:

  ```
  region sum = whole sum / number of centers of masses
  ```

4.for each center of mass

- start a region
- and incrementally increase the size until it sum match region sum
- avoid intersection of regions (use some map of usage for that)
- if region has the desired sum or has nowhere to grow stop

You will have to tweak this algorithm a little to suite your needs and input data

Hope it helps a little ...

Answer (score 0):

**Standard deviation** is way to measure that whether the divisions are close to equal. Lower standard deviation means closer the sums are.

As the problem seems n-p like clustering problems , [Genetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) can be used to get good solutions to the problem :-

> 1. Standard deviation can be used as fitness measure for chromosomes.
> 2. Consider k contagious regions then each gene(element) will have one of the k values which maintain the contagious nature of the regions.
> 3. apply genetic algorithm on the chromosomes and get the best chromosome for that value of k after a fixed amount of generations.
> 4. vary k from 2 to n and get best chromosome by applying genetic algorithms.