# Putting arrays in 'n' groups of equal lengths

Tags: arrays, algorithm

What is the best approach for creating **"n"** groups of arrays with the total length of all the arrays to be as close to equal as possible?

Looking for an algorithm that might output something like this:

```
Data Set (L=array length): [L:3],[L:1],[L:7],[L:4],[L:2] 

n=2: 
[L:3],[L:4],[L:1] = 8 total
[L:7],[L:2] = 9 total

n=3
[L:7]
[L:4],[L:1]
[L:3],[L:2]
```

After creating the example above I realize the phrase "close to equal" could be a bit ambiguous depending on how you define "equal".

I have a layout of n columns.  Each array is an atomic group of items and must be displayed together.  I'm currently giving the columns an equal number of arrays and my results often looks something like this:

```
7 total arrays: 3 columns

_ _ _
. . .
_ . .
. . .
. . .
  . _
  . .
  .
  _
  .
  .
```

I'm sure there's a term for doing what I want with tons of great resources linked to it on google, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Not sure, but this looks a lot like the knapsack problem. If I'm right, you may be in for a bit of a disappointment, because it's NP-hard.

Comment: You might find solution here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545663/divide-2d-array-into-continuous-regions-of-as-equal-as-possible-sums/21547838#21547838

Answer (score 2):

You are basically facing a variation of [Bin-packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) and [Subset Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problems, which are [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

Here is a reduction from [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) (special case of subset sum which is also NP-Complete) to your problen:

Partition Problem:

Given an input set `S`, find a partition to two distinct subsets `S1,S1` such that `S1 [union] S2 = S` and `S1 [intersection] S2 = {}`, and `sum(S1)=sum(S2)`.

Now, given an instance of partition `S={s1,...,s_n}` create data set `[L:s1],...[L:s_n]` and `n=2`.

Now, it is easy to see that a solution to your problem is a solution to the partition problem, and vise versa - and thus a solution to your problem effectively solves partition-problem.

Since partition problem is NP-Hard -so does this problem - and thus there is no known efficient (polynomial) solution to it, and most believe one does not exist.

Regarding the relationship to binpacking - note that your problem is basically binpacking with `size(bin) = sum(lengths)/n`

---

Note: In here I assumed you are working only with lengths, if you are working with actual elements, this reduction is not polynomial in the input size and the proof falls.

Comment: It is kinda like bin packing but where the bin cap is variable, i guess.  I would love to accept this but honestly, most of that is over my head.  The solution I'm looking for doesn't need to be perfect but just do a good job of distributing the elements so no single "bin" ends up with the largest arrays

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes I think I may do something like this:

```
var arrays = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]];
//number of bins
var n = 3;
var bins = [];
//init bins
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
  bins.push(new Array());
}
var i = 0;
while(arrays.length > 0){
  var array = elements.remove[0];
  var smallBin=0;
  var smallLength;
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    if(smallLength){
       if(bin[i].length < smallLength){
         smallLength = bin[i].length;
         smallBin = i;
       }
    }else{
       smallLength = bin[i].length;
    }
  }
  bins[smallBin].push(array);
}
```

I just typed this out in SO and haven't tested it yet.

I'm sure there are some combinations that would yield less than perfect results, but for my purpose it should work.